# Can not input password of my GitHub account when using hexo deploy

Tags: github, github-pages, hexo

I encounter this issue after I type "hexo deploy" in terminal. It asked me my GitHub username and password. The problem is I can only type in my username but not my password.

```
INFO  Deploying: git
INFO  Clearing .deploy_git folder...
INFO  Copying files from public folder...
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Username for 'https://github.com': Yancey2126
Password for 'https://Yancey2126@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Yancey2126/yancey2126.github.io.git/'
FATAL Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: http://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
Error: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Yancey2126/yancey2126.github.io.git/'
```

All I can do is to press Return and get an failed identification. Anyone knows what's going on? Thanks a lot~

Comment: Why can't you type your password?  Have your forgotten it?  Or is the real problem that you want / need to use your SSH key rather than a password?

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `git config credential helper`: you might have a password cache, which will provide automatically a password for the user `Yancey2126`.

For instance, with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you would be using the latest [Microsoft Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).
On mac, you would have [the osxkeychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/).